# How can I boot my Epic 4G Touch into CWM?

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, samsung-galaxy-s-2

Rooted using http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EwEYVB_ut4 process. Boot in cwm and the enter button (power button) doesn't work or is locked. Long press of button will reboot the device though. Downloaded latest cwm via ROM Manager and hit "Restart into Recovery" from the ROM Manager UI. Power button still doesn't work in cwm, except for long press. Now though, the device will only boot into cwm. Pulled battery, start and same thing... cwm.

Reapplied http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EwEYVB_ut4 and still have the same issue, device restarts into cmw only AND the power button only works on long press so I can't wipe and install any other ROMs on my SD to try to get out of this.

Comment: The volume buttons work, I assume?  I'd try re-flashing CWM from ROM manager, making sure that it doesn't try to flash the regular Epic 4G recovery instead of the Epic Touch.

Comment: Yes, the volume buttons work. But the phone only boots into CWM or Download mode, so I can't get to the OS or ROM Manager.  Thanks.

Comment: Ooh, I see, that's much different.

Comment: Flashed the lostKernal via Odin again and it restarted into CWM again. Select button still doesn't work in CWM. Been restarting over and over, pressed various combinations of buttons and it magically booted up ok. I afraid to restart the phone again though.

Comment: was this ever resolved....i was having the same issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Home button on the device (yeah, the Led lit one, it doesn't light up, but use it).  The Power button doesn't work for selecting options in recovery....

Answer (score 0):

If Recovery is broken and you can't boot into the OS, you're going to need to flash your device via Odin.  **Edit:** Now that you've got it booting I would still re-flash, personally, just to wipe away any issues.  [Download Odin here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1274337) and read that whole page so you understand how Odin works.  Odin's very powerful and can damage your phone if misused, but can save you many a time (as it has for me) if you do things right.

Then you need an "Odin-able" ROM to flash.  Stock is best, such as [this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1351761).  That page also has instructions for Odin, which are basically:

- Boot into Download Mode
- Connect your phone to the PC
- Start up Odin and ensure it sees the phone (reboot the phone and try again if not)
- Load the ROM you downloaded into the PDA field of Odin
- Hit Start and wait till it says it was successful before disconnecting your phone.

After you've flashed a stock ROM you could flash another that's pre-rooted or has CWM in order to get to where you want to be.  I would highly recommend that over trying the method that got you into this mess in the first place :).  [This rooting method](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1342728) seems better/simpler.  Flashing modified kernels can be pretty tricky, and you normally don't want to do that in order to root.  I always keep my kernels as close to stock as possible.